# Play YouTube videos from an array of video IDs : React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';
let videoIdList=["XM-HJT8_esM","AOMpxsiUg2Q"];
var videoId = videoIdList[0];
let i=0;
class YoutubePlayer extends Component {
    render() {
        const opts = {
            height: '390',
            width: '640',
            playerVars: { // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
                autoplay: 1
            }
        };

        return (
            <YouTube
                videoId={videoId}
                opts={opts}
                onReady={this._onReady}
                onEnd={this._onEnd}
            />
        );
    }

    _onReady(event) {
        // access to player in all event handlers via event.targe
        event.target.playVideo(videoIdList[i])
    }

    _onEnd(event) {
        videoId = videoIdList[i]
        event.target.playVideo(videoIdList[++i]);
        console.log(videoId);
    }
}
export default YoutubePlayer;
```

So I am trying to play youtube videos from a array of video ids. When a video ends I want to change the video to next video in the list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to maintain inner state with currently played video, and as soon as video is over, you will have to set next video in state which will re render the component again and start with next video. Below code should work.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import YouTube from '@u-wave/react-youtube';
import "./styles.css";
let videoIdList=["AOMpxsiUg2Q","XM-HJT8_esM","AOMpxsiUg2Q"];

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {};
this.i = 0;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({videoId: videoIdList[this.i]});
}

render() {
    const opts = {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: { // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
            autoplay: 1
        }
    };

    return (
        <YouTube
            video={this.state.videoId}
            opts={opts}
            onReady={this._onReady}
            onEnd={this._onEnd}
        />
    );
}

_onEnd = () => {
    this.setState({videoId: videoIdList[++this.i]});
 }

}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can check working code here -
https://codesandbox.io/s/7yk0vrzr36